# Sum of exponents equals delta function

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, summation

For a homework exercise i need to prove that 
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{i(k-\xi)n}|u(\xi)> =\delta(k-\xi)|u(\xi)>.$$
Where $\delta(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and zero elsewhere and $|u(\xi)>$ is just a vector with no special properties, but $-\pi \leq \xi \leq \pi$. 
Can anyone help me or at least give a hint?

Comment: What is your definition of delta function?

Comment: 1 at $k=\xi$ zero elsewhere

Comment: Hint: Look for the keyword "Poisson summation formula".

Comment: Usually the delta function characterized by saying $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)\,dx=f(0)$ whenever $f$ is well-behaved (sometimes meaning $f\in C^\infty$ and $f$ has bounded support).  That's not the same as $\delta(0)=1$ and $\delta(x)=0$ for $x\ne1$.  But there is a _measure_ $\mu$ that assigns measure $1$ to sets containing $0$ and $0$ to sets not containing $0$, and one can say that $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,d\mu(x)=f(0)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I have updated the post regarding your comments.